# horizontal listview in listview by xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to design a horizontal scroll list with xamarin.forms in a scrolling vertical list.
The json information is also available as an array within the array.

Comment: This is not a question.  Please read "How to Ask" in the help section before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You could set rotation to 270 in listview like following code.

```
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="MessagesLayoutFrame" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ContentView x:Name="MessagesLayoutFrameInner"  Padding="0"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="listview"

          RowHeight="240"
          VerticalOptions="Start"
          HeightRequest="240"
          WidthRequest="240"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          Rotation="270"
          HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ContentView Rotation="90" Padding="12">

                                <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Aspect="AspectFill" />


                        </ContentView>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Or used as this link to achieved a new `renderedViews:HorizontalListView`

https://www.sharpnado.com/a-real-horizontal-list-view/

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use stack layout inside listview with Orientation=Horizontal

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
</StackLayout>
```

you can also use xamarin new feature collection view

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-4-0-feature-preview-an-entirely-new-point-of-collectionview/